# Apache Kafka setup consumer error: "JSON Decoder Error: Extra data line 1 column 4 char 4"

Tags: python, json, apache-kafka

The consumer `bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server kafka:9092 --topic my_topic` works and I can see the logs as: `2021-12-11T22:40:13.800Z {"ts":1639262395.220755,"uid":"CiaUp427FXwzqySsOh","id.orig_h":"fe80::f816:3eff:fef4:a877","id.orig_p":5353,"id.resp_h":"ff02::fb","id.resp_p":5353,"proto":"udp","service":"dns","duration":0.40987586975097659,"orig_bytes":1437,"resp_bytes":0,"conn_state":"S0","missed_bytes":0,"history":"D","orig_pkts":4,"orig_ip_bytes":1629,"resp_pkts":0,"resp_ip_bytes":0}`

However with the consumer code listed below I am getting: `JSON Decoder Error: Extra data line 1 column 4 char 4"` which seems to be an easy error related to parsing the data, which has each log starting with the date:time as shown above. Meaning the consumer gets the first log but cannot parse it.

Easy enough, yet it seems I cannot get around it as this is part of the KafkaConsumer object. If anyone can give a hint or show how to do it it would be great. Thanks and Regards, M

```
from json import loads  
from kafka import KafkaConsumer, TopicPartition 
import threading, time
from IPython.display import clear_output


KAFKA_SERVER='10.10.10.10:9092'
TOPIC = 'my_topic'
AUTO_OFFSET_RESET = 'earliest'
CONSUMER_TIME_OUT=1000 #miliseconds
MAXIMUM_SECONDS=0.01 #seconds

class TrafficConsumer():
    def __init__(self, offset=AUTO_OFFSET_RESET, verbose=False, close=True):
        try:
            self.__traffic_consumer = KafkaConsumer(  
                 TOPIC,  
                 bootstrap_servers = [KAFKA_SERVER],  
                 auto_offset_reset = offset,  
                 enable_auto_commit = True,  
                 #group_id = GROUP_ID,  
                 value_deserializer = lambda x : loads(x.decode('utf-8')),
                 consumer_timeout_ms = CONSUMER_TIME_OUT,
                #on_commit = self.commit_completed(),
                 )
            self.__traffic_consumer.subscribe([TOPIC])
            threading.Thread.__init__(self)
            self.stop_event = threading.Event()
        except Exception as e:
            print("Consumer is not accessible. Check: the connections and the settings in attributes_kafka.", e)
        self.set_conn_log_traffic(verbose=verbose, close=close)
        
    def stop(self):
        self.stop_event.set()
        
    def get_consumer(self):
        return self.__traffic_consumer
    
    def set_conn_log_traffic(self, verbose=False, close=True):
        while not self.stop_event.is_set():
            for ind_flow in self.__traffic_consumer.poll(2):
                print(ind_flow)
                
                if self.stop_event.is_set():
                    break        
        if close: self.__traffic_consumer.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data isn't proper json. It includes a timestamp before the json object, which cannot be decoded using `json.loads`.

You should verify how the producer is sending data since the timestamp is part of the value, rather than the Kafka record timestamp

Or, you can handle the problem in a the consumer by using a different deserializer function

For example

```
def safe_deserialize(value):
  _, data = value.decode('utf-8').split(" ", 1)
  return json.loads(data)

...

 KafkaConsumer(
   ...
   value_deserializer = safe_deserialize,
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I figured. How come the consumer `bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh ` picks up the logs? Is it using a different approach? I would rather deal with this on the consumer side obviously. The producer is not accessible to me and shared by other projects. Can you point me in the right direction on how to deserialize it? Specifically the error comes from `for ind_flow in self.__traffic_consumer.poll(2):`

Comment: I tried both `value_deserializer = lambda x : loads(x.decode('ascii'))` and got `JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 5 (char 4)` and then `value_deserializer = msgpack.unpackb` and got `ExtraData: unpack(b) received extra data.`

Comment: Solved this by commenting OUT value_deserializer `#value_deserializer = lambda x : loads(x.decode('utf-8')),`  (so no lambda function for the value_deserializer was set) and by changing `for ind_flow in self.__traffic_consumer.poll(2):` to `for ind_flow in self.__traffic_consumer:`

Comment: It's definitely not msgpack data... If you want to parse the json, you can only convert as a string, then remove `2021-12-11T22:40:13.800Z` prefix using substring/slice functions and then you can parse the remainder as json. But like I said, you should really fix this in the producer

Comment: Now the iterator returns ConsumerRecords objects. To access the log I used the `x.values()` method. Then I converted bytes-string to string and split to remove the date-time substring. The remaining substring was converted to dict using `import ast` and `my_dict = ast.literal_eval(my_string)`

Comment: I don't think you need `ast`... `json.loads()` should still work